# Progress Bar in Theme

Tags: c#, android, xml, styles

I have been having problems with incorporating a Progress Bar into my splash screen. I have an XML file called splash_setup,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/background">

  <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" />

  <ProgressBar
      style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
      android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This file is used as background for 'splashTheme' (in Styles.XML) as following,

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="splashTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_setup</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

The splashTheme is used in splashActivity (the splash executes database initialisation and then finished),

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/appName", Theme = "@style/splashTheme",
 MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
```

So to my problem... the splash_setup code runs fine without  tags, but when they are in I get the following error,

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_setup.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020002

Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a [layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) not a [drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). android:windowBackground attribute in style allows only drawable which may include shapes and/or layer lists. If you really wish to show a progressbar, then you need an activity.

Comment: Thanks, I will just stick with displaying the logo.